# How do I clear cached credentials from my Windows Profile?

Tags: authentication, windows, certificates

Windows seems to be saving my credentials for a variety of applications (terminal servers, etc) and I'd like to purge this data.

How can I backup and purge this data?

Comment: Is there a way to automate the removal of cached credentials via a PowerShell script that I can invoke?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The utility to delete cached credentials is hard to find.  It stores both certificate data and also user passwords.

Open a command prompt, or enter the following in the run command

```
 rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
```

[image: Image of cached credentials]

Windows 7 makes this easier by creating an icon in the control panel called "Credential manager"

[image]

Comment: good write up for both Admins and End-Users.  Could have used a route guide to the Credential Manager, for those less-Admin knowledgeable.

Comment: Excellent. This command saved my day. Didn't know about it

Comment: My control panel item for this is hidden due to company group policies. The command you gave is the only way I could access my cached credentials. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

There is also a command-line utility:

```
C:\> cmdkey /?

Creates, displays, and deletes stored user names and passwords.

The syntax of this command is:

CMDKEY [{/add | /generic}:targetname {/smartcard | /user:username {/pass{:password}}} | /delete{:targetname | /ras} | /list{:targetname}]

Examples:

  To list available credentials:
     cmdkey /list
     cmdkey /list:targetname

  To create domain credentials:
     cmdkey /add:targetname /user:username /pass:password
     cmdkey /add:targetname /user:username /pass
     cmdkey /add:targetname /user:username
     cmdkey /add:targetname /smartcard

  To create generic credentials:
     The /add switch may be replaced by /generic to create generic credentials

  To delete existing credentials:
     cmdkey /delete:targetname

  To delete RAS credentials:
     cmdkey /delete /ras
```

Link to documentation page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey

Comment: Thank you. Helped me to create a `cmd` file to delete the hundreds of crap entries I had.

Answer (score 8):

Use `cmd`:

```
NET USE
```

(to see what you're connected to)

```
NET USE * /DELETE
```

(to delete all connections)

`net use` info is not the same info as listed in keymgr or credential mgr.

Answer (score 6):

FYI, I just encountered a case where a credential (possibly corrupt, since it showed up under an entry named with only two, odd Unicode characters) appeared only in the `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr` interface, and not in the Credential Manager interface found in the Windows 7 control panel.  So it may be worth checking both interfaces for cached credentials.